# Laravel Mix add Specific File for authorized user

Tags: css, laravel, laravel-mix

Just started using the Laravel Mix. Now I have bundled all the main css, that is required into a file named test.css, and it is loading fine.

Now, there are two more stylesheets, namely a.css and b.css. What I want to do is to merge that into the test.css that is being generated by mix, only if a user is authenticated.

Now, In simple blade, we would have added the

```
@auth // Load css here @endauth
```

But, how to do that with mix, didn't found a single piece of information for the same anywhere.

Thanks

Comment: CSS is not a programming language. You can only create a new CSS file specific for authenticated users or just merge it into `test.css`. But CSS wil never know if a user is authenticated or not

Comment: Is there any way to handle, that via Laravel Mix, since if I load those initially, then until the other user's logs in, those two files would be used unnecessarily?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS is not a programming language so you can't use an if statement to know if a user is authenticated in CSS.

In the docs from laravel [mix](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/mix). I don't know if you use any CSS preprocessor but I guess this should work for just CSS files:

```
mix.styles([
    '/resources/assets/css/partial1.css',
    '/resources/assets/css/partial2.css',
    '/resources/assets/css/main.css',
], 'public/css/test.css');

mix.styles([
    '/resources/assets/css/a.css',
    '/resources/assets/css/b.css',
], 'public/css/admin.css');
```

And then just load the `admin.css` when a user is logged in.

Comment: I thought of that too, however, let's say that if I need only a specific css file, will it be worth to minify it or use it directly?

Comment: It kind of depends on the file sizes. But every request to load a file takes time. So ultimately it might be faster to just merge everything in one single file. Minifying is always recommended.

Comment: Agreed on that. Thanks!